# Can ping but can't RDP or access UNC path ofter reboot Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, troubleshooting

I rebooted a server after a Symantec installation. I did this from home and have no way to physically connect.

Rebooted the server and now I cannot access it from UNC path or RDP. Using a VPN to connect.

I can ping the server and get a response but that's it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Provide more detail. What is the exact error message when connecting. Is the port open?

Comment: Endpoint protection ?, if so, did you did a light installation & remove the firewall protection from it ? If no, please open the port from your Symantec's console. else, check your firewall (by opening a remote 'service' windows with the mmc & closing the firewall service if you cant rdp in)